# Who did Ronan kill in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In the movie Ronan gets out of a tub, gets his hammer, and kills a Nova Corp member. Was he special in any way? I always thought that had to have some significance besides him killing a random soldier.

Comment: My impulse is that, no, it's no one in particular.

Comment: He was a red-shirt.

Answer (score 8):

Currently we have no answer as to the identity of the [Xandarian](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Xandarians) prisoner. Although this can always be retconned in a later film, he is most likely just some random [corpsman](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_Corps) captured by [Ronan](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser)'s men. Even without knowing the man's identity, however, the scene still serves to show the audience not only Ronan's motivation, but also his villainy & willingness to kill.

[image]

> **Ronan:** They call me a terrorist... a radical... a zealot. Because I
>   obey the ancient laws of my people the Kree and punish those who do
>   not. Because I do not forgive your people for taking the life of my
>   father, and his father, and his father before him. A thousand years of
>   war between us will NOT be forgotten.
>
> **Prisoner:** [*struggles in harness*] You can’t do this. Our governments
>   signed a peace treaty!
>
> **Ronan:** Yes, my government knows no shame. You Xandarians and your
>   culture are a disease.
>
> **Prisoner:** You will never rule Xandar.
>
> **Ronan:** No... I will cure it!  [*yells as he swings axe and crushes
>   prisoner's head*]

Comment: When I first watched this, I always wondered why everyone would call him "Terrence" when his name was Ronan, of coarse he says "terrorist".